# Half of my screen can't be used

Tags: lubuntu, screen

[image]

this happened this morning and I didn't know what to do

Comment: Do you mean the dark block on the left? How does it behave?

Comment: yes, i can move mouse over there

Comment: it's been fixed, it's just a panel and I just have to delete it. maybe someone accidentally made the panel lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a panel, delete it. Just right-click on the panel, and click remove:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue when using VirtualBox. I changed Pointing Device to USB Tables (it does not work with PS2).

UPDATE: turning off a screensaver solves the issue. Not sure if it connected to Pointing Device.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U92z7.png)